# CI - Loading controller with Javascript button

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, codeigniter

I admittedly am not very proficient with Javascript (and subsequently AJAX). I have a button that you click to vote on a page. Once clicked, the page drops and expands the section so that you can see the comments below it (so that the voter will not be swayed by the comments). This works beautifully, but unfortunately, clicking the button does not actually load the PHP controller to submit the vote to the database.

View:

```
<div class="vote clearfix">
    <ul class="list1 clearfix">
        <li class="css3">
            <a href="<?=base_url()?>vote/submit_vote/<?=$post?>/1/1" class="button1 css3">
            <span>Button Text</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('ul.list1 li a').click(function() {
    $('a.button1').removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().find('a.button1').addClass("active");
    $("div#content div.comments").fadeIn('slow');
    var col1Height = $("div#left-pannel").height() -63 ;
    $('div#sidebar').css("min-height", col1Height );
    return false;
});
```

I would like this button to submit the vote to a controller. What would be the best way to fix the button so that it links normally?

Comment: Is the content for div.comments already loaded on the page before the vote button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click handler needs two things: preventDefault(), and an AJAX method such as jQuery's $.ajax() or $.get().

preventDefault() will prevent the default action of navigating the page to the href value. Add a parameter to the click event to represent the event, and call preventDefault() on that.

$.ajax() or $.get() will perform the action of hitting the URL to cast the vote. Personally I prefer $.ajax(), it performs a GET request by default but you can set the type to POST. There are many other options available such as dataType (json, text, xml, etc.). The success and error functions are straight-forward to implement too.

JavaScript:

```
$('ul.list1 li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // cache this for scope change
    var $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        success: function() {
            // your original JavaScript here
            $('a.button1').removeClass('active');

            $this.addClass('active'); // no need for .parent().find()

            $('div#content div.comments').fadeIn('slow');
            var col1Height = $("div#left-pannel").height() - 63;
            $('div#sidebar').css("min-height", col1Height);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Sorry, your vote was not successful.');
        }
    });
});
```

I also changed how you called addClass() in your code. First, we needed to cache $(this) since "this" will no longer refer to the clicked element in the success function. Second, based on the HTML you provided, the element you need to find, 'a.button', *is* the element that was clicked. If that is the case, we can drop .parent().find('a.button') and just operate on $this directly.

More on jQuery.ajax(): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Feel free to ask questions about the code. I hope that helps!

Comment: This worked exactly as I wanted. You killed it man, thanks!!! Thanks for the incredible feedback, everyone. It really was eye-opening.

Comment: I'm glad that was helpful. I really appreciate the feedback too!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul.list1 li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a.button1').removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().find('a.button1').addClass("active");

    $("div#content div.comments").fadeOut('slow')
    .load($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn('slow');

    var col1Height = $("div#left-pannel").height() -63 ;
    $('div#sidebar').css("min-height", col1Height );
});
```

`div#content div.comments` will be replaced with new content from the server if your view echos anything as html.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere on your javascript code you need to actually call the Controller,

Depending on how you build your controller you can do something like this

```
$('ul.list1 li a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('a.button1').addClass("active");
    $('div#content div.comments').load('http://url/to/the/controller/plus/params/to/cast/the/vote');

    $("div#content div.comments").fadeIn('slow');
    var col1Height = $("div#left-pannel").height() -63 ;
    $('div#sidebar').css("min-height", col1Height );
    return false;
});
```

In case you are expecting post variables on your controller the request would be a little different.

Also i'm assuming that there is a div.comments somewhere in your html.

Can you post the method from you controller that handles the request?

Comment: Sorry for such a delay. The problem is that the controller isn't being loaded at all. The problem is that the JS is in a separate file with a need for the url to be dynamically generated.

Comment: @blackairplane
You can use something like this then:
`$('div#content div.comments').load($(this).attr('href'));`
instead of
`$('div#content div.comments').load('http://url/to/the/controller/plus/params/to/cast/the/vote');`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
$('ul.list1 li a').click(function() {
    var a = this;

    $('a.button1').removeClass("active");
    $(a).parent().find('a.button1').addClass("active");
    $("div#content div.comments").hide().load($(a).attr("href"), function(){ $(this).fadeIn('slow'); });
    var col1Height = $("div#left-pannel").height() -63 ;
    $('div#sidebar').css("min-height", col1Height );
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This worked to post the vote (Thanks!!), but it broke the fadeIn effect.

Comment: try that, it won't `fadeIn` until after the content is loaded

Comment: Hmmm.. That didn't seem to make a difference. Sorry to be a noob. I'm just learning JS/AJAX. Strictly a PHP guy.

Comment: do you have a test page i can look at?

Comment: actually i just updated that to hide the comments div before loading them THEN fadeIn, that should do it

Comment: Ok, it seems to show the comment section for a split second before hiding it. I can prob set up a test page if you think that'll help. It'll just take a bit since the project's on lock-down and running on CodeIgniter.

Comment: if a stylesheet hides div.comments in a rule { display:none; } that could cause it to fade in then, when finished fading, disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make AJAX call to your controller

```
<div class="vote clearfix">
<ul class="list1 clearfix">
    <li class="css3">
        <a href="<?=base_url()?>vote/submit_vote/<?=$post?>/1/1" class="button1 css3">
        <span>Button Text</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('ul.list1 li a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var obj = $(this);

  $.get(obj.attr('href'),function(res){
    if(res == 1) //assuming your controller returns 1 on success
    {
      $('a.button1').removeClass("active");
      $(this).parent().find('a.button1').addClass("active");
      $("div#content div.comments").fadeIn('slow');
      var col1Height = $("div#left-pannel").height() -63 ;
      $('div#sidebar').css("min-height", col1Height );
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('ul.list1 li a').click(function() {
    $('a.button1').removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().find('a.button1').addClass("active");
    $("div#content div.comments").fadeIn('slow');
    var col1Height = $("div#left-pannel").height() -63 ;
    $('div#sidebar').css("min-height", col1Height );
    var post = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
       url: '<?=base_url()?>vote/submit_vote/' + post +'/1/1'
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="vote clearfix">
    <ul class="list1 clearfix">
        <li class="css3">
            <a id="<?=$post?>" href="#" class="button1 css3">
            <span>Button Text</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```